# Warning fsockopen() in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

(sorry for my english ... i'm french)

I'm using Symfony 4 and PHP 7.2.1 (the one in MAMP) and MySQL. My computer is an iMac with mac OS X HighSierra.
The error message in var/log/dev.log is the following one :

```
php.DEBUG: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) ...
```

In my PHP.ini i have the option "allow_url_fopen = On"

How can i found an issue to correct this warning ?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Turn off xdebug.scream in your php.ini

Comment: I'm going to try this ... Thank you

Comment: Unfortunatly, there is no xdebug.scream in my php.ini ...

Comment: Anything about scream? scream.enabled = ?

Comment: no ... there is no scream

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you.. :( But this is just a warning message. Last think you can do is to find the line in the file that shows error and put @ before fsockopen.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:**

```
 $val = '123';
 $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 8000);
 fwrite($fp, "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
 fwrite($fp, "Host: localhost \r\n");
 fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
 fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: " . strlen($val) . "\r\n");
 fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
 fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
 fwrite($fp, $val);
```

Comment: Can you explain what that code does and how that solves the problem?